# Elasticsearch query with different fields

Tags: elasticsearch, search

here an exemple of my documents

```
{
    "@timestamp": "2020-04-24T19:36:52.484Z",
    "token": "123",
    "application": "sso_api_v3",
    "ssoapiv3_method": "GET",
    "ssoapiv3_error_description": "Your access token has expired",
    "code": 401,
    "message": "\"message\"",
    "level": 6,
    "facility": "sso_api_v3",
    "type": "gelf"
}
[...]
{
    "@timestamp": "2020-04-24T19:37:52.484Z",
    "token": "123",
    "application": "sso_api_v3",
    "ssoapiv3_method": "GET",
    "ssoapiv3_error_description": "Your access token has expired",
    "code": 200,
    "message": "\"message\"",
    "level": 6,
    "facility": "sso_api_v3",
    "type": "gelf"
}
[...]
```

I have a huge amount of request and I would like to do a search in order to get documents with the same token but but with code 200 and 401. I can get all 200, all 401 but I'm unable to have this for the same token.

Answer (score 1):

There are two way to do this.

**1. [Terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html)**

Query:

```
{
  "size": 0, 
   "aggs": {
     "code": {
       "filter": {
         "terms": {
           "code": [
             200,401 --> returns all documengts with code 200 / 401
           ]
         }
       },
       "aggs": {
         "token": { --> creates group of tokens and fetched doc under each
           "terms": {
             "field": "token.keyword",
             "size": 10
           },
           "aggs": {
             "docs": {
               "top_hits": {
                 "size": 10
               }
             }
           }
         }
       }
     }
   }
}
```

Result:

```
"aggregations" : {
    "code" : {
      "doc_count" : 1,
      "token" : {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
        "buckets" : [
          {
            "key" : "123",
            "doc_count" : 1,
            "docs" : {
              "hits" : {
                "total" : {
                  "value" : 1,
                  "relation" : "eq"
                },
                "max_score" : 1.0,
                "hits" : [
                  {
                    "_index" : "index9",
                    "_type" : "_doc",
                    "_id" : "16UKynEBAWHHnYGORq-d",
                    "_score" : 1.0,
                    "_source" : {
                      "@timestamp" : "2020-04-24T19:36:52.484Z",
                      "token" : "123",
                      "application" : "sso_api_v3",
                      "ssoapiv3_method" : "GET",
                      "ssoapiv3_error_description" : "Your access token has expired",
                      "code" : 401,
                      "message" : """"message"""",
                      "level" : 6,
                      "facility" : "sso_api_v3",
                      "type" : "gelf"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

**2. [Field collapsing](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-request-collapse.html)**

Returns top 1 document on a group field. You can get other documents  under that group
using inner_hits

Query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "code": [
        200,
        401
      ]
    }
  },
  "collapse": {
    "field": "token.keyword",
    "inner_hits": {
            "name": "docs", 
            "size": 10, 
            "sort": [{ "@timestamp": "asc" }] 
        }
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunatelyn it does not seems to work, by example I get a token, but I only have 200.What I want is token for which I have some documents with 200, and some with 401.